# Android + Kotlin + Hilt: Injecting into object class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I will focus in injecting Context, but my question applies to whatever dependency it is, like a repository or service class.

I have an object as follows:

```
object MyObject {

    lateinit var appContext: Context

    doWhatever(appContext: Context){ => This is where I need context
    }

    fun myMethod() {
        val baseClass = BaseClass()
        doWhatever(appContext)
    }
}
```

I already know Hilt cannot inject into objects, but it can inject into classes, so I'm trying the next approach.

```
object MyObject : ProviderClass() {

    doWhatever(appContext: Context){
    }

    fun myMethod() {
        val baseClass = BaseClass()
        doWhatever(appContext)
    }
}

abstract class ProviderClass {

    @Inject
    lateinit var appContext: Context
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to do field injection into ProviderClass and making the field available through inheritance, but it is also failing with **"lateinit var appContext has not been initialized"**.

This is where I provide dependencies:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Dependencies {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): Context {
        return appContext
    }
}
```

What's wrong? How can I inject any dependency into an object?

Comment: For field injection, it's not enough to just declare the fields with @Inject annotation, https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported, use constructor injection with `@Singleton` annotaion instead of `object`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @IR42. I'll read the documentation you've provided, but meanwhile, ¿could you give a practical example? On the other hand, ¿Are you referring to use a class MyObject instead an object MyObject? I've also tried with no success. I'm using an object so I can access all methods in a static way. I know I can declare a "companion object" in a class to work with static methods, but this way I don't know how to access the dependencies injected in the container's class constructor. I'm confused, so maybe an example on how to literally "move" my own example to a class as you say?

Comment: On the other hand, you say @Inject is not enough to provide field injection, but if you read my post again you'll see I have a dependencies class with #Singleton and #Provides over the "provideContext" method, and the class is decorated with #InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class). that is also not enough? I cannot understand how can such a common task like injecting a context can be so difficult :(

Comment: BTW, I'm already reading the link you've provided, and it mentions to use EntryPoint, and if you see the line "val hiltEntryPoint =
      EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(appContext, ExampleContentProviderEntryPoint::class.java)" you'll notice a context is needed and context is just what I'm trying to inject!! It's like a vicious circle for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inject dependency into **Object**

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface SomeInterface{
    val dep: YourDependecyClass
}
```

but you can access dependencies like this, to do this you need context in places where hilt direct injection is not supported yet have access to context

```
val x:SomeInterface = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(applicationContext, SomeInterface::class.java)
```

Below image is not directly related to answer, just a reference for the discussion we had in comment section
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying @Abhijith mogaveera. I've read documentation and also tried your example and it works! But what if the dependency is Context itself? For the line: EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(applicationContext, SomeInterface::class.java) context is needed, and trying to use EntryPoint for that ends in a "vicious circle", I'm sure injecting context should be much easier, but how? how could I inject ApplicationContext? Could you edit and add a full example for that? Because in some of my utility classes (objects) I need Context.

Comment: Simply in short, using hilt we can't inject dependency to places where context is not reached,  Alternative solution would creating extension function from context class or another option would be am adding a screen shot take look at that and context is already provided by hilt u just need to annotate it with @ApplicationContext

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation and solution @Abhijith mogaveera, it was very useful to me. According to what you say let me ask you one last question: I was using "object{}" instead of "class{}" just because I like accessing utility/helper methods in a static way (ex. MyHelper.DoSomething()), but as I cannot inject Context in objects (and I need it for some helpers) maybe -aiming to use pure Hilt- I could just use classes, inject the context as you mentioned, and for the static way of accessing methods I should use a "Companion object" plus #JvmStatic decorator on methods. Right?

Comment: yes if u don't need context there else if u use companion object inside class u can't access variable or methods which is not static so u cant access context there

Comment: And what if I need Context in "static" (companion object) methods @Abhijith mogaveera? I'm trying creating an instance of the "parent" class (the one with constructor injected context) like this: companion object { val context: Context = ParentClass().context }, but it is obviously complaining because ParentClass instantiation needs context... In the end, I need context in helper statically accessed methods class. Why is so difficult to implement so?

Comment: I'll answer myself, not yet convinced, but... I could use an object for my helper methods and include an "init" fun like this: fun init(appContext: Context){ this.appContext = appContext } and initialise context in "init" in Application class at startup. It is working, but this is not Hilt injection. Anyway, I think I'll go with this.

Comment: It is funny (maybe ironic), because you don't need context in activities, you already have a context in them. You may need context in a helper class (for example), and it is most likely you'll expect your methods to be statically accessed, but Hilt doesn't provide you a way for a context to be accessible in them. For me it's nonsense...

Comment: ha ha activity it self is a context

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with this block of code:

```
abstract class ProviderClass {
  @Inject
  lateinit var appContext: Context
}
```

First, hilt will not know which Context to provide, because Android has  many components with that have Context, e.g Services, Activities, and Application. Thus, hilt has no clue which component's Context to inject.

Rather, and the hilt Qualifier annotation @Application Context as follows:

```
abstract class ProviderClass {
   @Inject
   @ApplicationContext
   lateinit var appContext: Context
}
```